# Is there a way to save all ALTER TABLE queries?

Tags: mysql

For example i or someone do some **ALTER TABLE QUERIES**:

```
ALTER TABLE `admin` CHANGE `nome` `nome` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE `admin` CHANGE `cognome` `nome` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL;
.....
```

Dynamically I always want to save them?
Or intercept the event.
What would be a good way?

Comment: You can enable the query log on the server.

Comment: Or the binary log.